# MVC3 and Session Scalability

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session, scalability

I am building an MVC 3 Application and have a question about one example scenario.

I have two entities - `Order` and `OrderDetails`.
Order data is filled on one page, detail is added, edited, deleted on other three pages.
Once order and details are filled I save this bunch of data to database.

As you can see, during user work and before data is saved to the DB, I need to store the order and details data into some kind of in-memory or similar object.

Now, if I store this object in `Session` then I am breaking scalability - application cannot be spanned across multiple machines.

Is there a Pattern or Approach which allows scalability and do scenarios like described?

*Note: Solution other than Sql-Server Session State*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at the **State Server Session**

*StateServer mode, which stores session state in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: +1 as this gives an 'almost' transparent up-port from session